# Using Java 8 streams with lambdas to process a for loop, invoking a method with multiple parms

Tags: java, loops, lambda

I have a for loop, processing two string lists, which invokes a method with multiple parms, returning an object, which gets added to a List

I want to effectively utilize stream/lambda for this, can someone guide me
I have two incoming string lists "AAA, BBB, CCC" and a corresponding list of quantities as "1, 3, 11"

```
final List<someObj> someObjs = new ArrayList<someObj>() ;

final List<String> codesList = Arrays.asList(codes.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
final List<String> qtysList  = Arrays.asList(qtys.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

for (String code: codesList){
    someObjs.add(addThis(code, qtysList.get(index++)));//
}

return someObj;
```

How can I convert this using lambdas ?  Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you want to use Java 8 streams?

Comment: @SamOrozco I mentioned that in the question, i will add it to title

Comment: Just a one question. Quantities should per list or together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this,

```
final List<SomeObj> someObjs = IntStream.range(0, codesList.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> addThis(codesList.get(i), qtysList.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks...This is turning out to be an art form :) Not to sound too greedy, but any way to incorporate the creation of the two String Lists from the comma delimited strings? I know it might make it unreadable, but was just wondering if it was at all possible. (Seems like there is no end to this stream magic.)

Comment: Found the stream construct from Mohsen's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599847/convert-comma-separated-string-to-list-without-intermediate-container just need a way to plug it in I guess, if possible

Comment: @killjoy this way it can be created:   Collections.list(new StringTokenizer(str, ",")).stream()
      .map(token -> (String) token)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())