# Arrays.stream(array) vs Arrays.asList(array).stream()

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, java-8, java-stream

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391028/arrays-aslist-vs-arrays-stream-to-use-foreach) question it has already been answered that both expressions are equal, but in this case they produce different results. For a given `int[] scores`, why does this work:

```
Arrays.stream(scores)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

...but this does not:

```
Arrays.asList(scores).stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

As far as I know `.stream()` can be called on any Collection, which Lists definitely are. The second code snippet just returns a stream containing the array as a whole instead of the elements.

Answer (score 17):

The behavior you see is not specific to `Stream`s.
`Arrays.asList(scores)` returns a `List<int[]>` when you pass to it an `int[]`, since a generic type parameter can't be replaced by a primitive type. Therefore, when you call `asList(T... a)`, the compiler uses `int[]` in place of `T`.

If you change `scores` to `Integer[]`, you'll get the output you expect (i.e. `Arrays.asList(scores)` will return a `List<Integer>`).

Comment: I see. It's just strange because I remember me doing stuff like that in the past and it worked. Would it have worked if I had declared the List in advance like this: `List<Integer> scoresAsList = new ArrayList<>(scores);`?

Comment: @AdHominem That wouldn't work, since you can't pass an array to an `ArrayList` constructor. You can only pass a Collection.

Comment: As a side note, `Stream.of(scores).forEach(System.out::println);` does the same as `Arrays.asList(scores).stream().forEach(System.out::println);`…

Answer (score 10):

The reason the second code snippet does not work is that there is no such thing as `List<int>` in Java. That is why `Arrays.asList(scores)` does not produce what you expect.

Switching from `int[]` to `Integer[]` would fix this problem, in the sense that the two pieces of code would produce identical results. However, your code would be less efficient, because all `int`s would be boxed.

In fact, efficiency is the reason behind having overloads of `stream` for primitive arrays. Your call `Arrays.stream(scores)` is routed to `stream(int[] array)`, producing `IntStream` object. Now you can apply `.forEach(System.out::println)`, which calls `println(int)`, again avoiding boxing.

Comment: Pray for Project Valhalla then :D

Comment: @java8.being: since writing a wrapper `List` for an `int[]` is roughly ten lines of code, and for streaming, `Arrays.stream(scores)` already works, I don’t see the point of praying for something for which we don’t even know what and how it will change about this issue…

Comment: @Holger I meant for this line: `The reason the second code snippet does not work is that there is no such thing as List<int> in Java.`

Comment: @java8.being: If Project Valhalla manages to change that, there will be no real difference between a `List<int>` and a `List<@NonNull Integer>` and `Arrays.asList` will continue to do what it does today, for compatibility reasons…

Answer (score 1):

**Arrays.asList** expects arrays of Object not arrays of **primitives**.
It does not complain on compile time because arrays of primitive is an object.

It can take  one object as list but what is inside that **object**(arrays of primitive is an object) cannot be convert to list.

Arrays of primitive can be convert to stream using
`IntStream`,`DoubleStream` and `LongStream`

like this

```
double[] doubleArray = {1.1,1.2,1.3};

DoubleStream.of(doubleArray).forEach(System.out::println);


int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

IntStream.of(intArray).forEach(System.out::println);


long[] longArray = {1L,2L,3L};

LongStream.of(longArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? It least you should comment.

Comment: It sure helps, how int[] score can be convert to stream.

Comment: much better now +1